# Cual es la mejor manera incluir las clases en php?

Tags: php

Cual es la mejor manera de usar las clases en php?

Es decir, se puede hacer un

```
include ("clase.php");
```

o supongo que también funcionará con un

```
require_once("clase.php");
```

No sé si hay más maneras ni sé cual es la mejor manera de usarlo, en la página de php tampoco es que se explique demasuado bien.

Comment: La pregunta parece ser muy distinta del ejemplo: una cosa es la "manera" de usar una clase, otra cosa es como incluir un archivo.

Comment: @Pavlo La pregunta es ¿cuál es la mejor manera o cuál es la diferencia entre `include()` y `require_once()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De hecho en las documentaciones oficiales de PHP explican bastante bien las diferencias de usar `include("class.php");` a usar `require_once("class.php");`

Te resumo:

> **require_once**
>
> La sentencia require_once es idéntica a [require](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.require.php) excepto que PHP
>   verificará si el archivo ya ha sido incluido y si es así, no se
>   incluye (require) de nuevo.

Ahora bien, `require` nos dice:

> **require**
>
> La sentencia require es idéntica a [include](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php) **excepto que en
>   caso de fallo producirá un error fatal de nivel** `E_COMPILE_ERROR`. En
>   otras palabras, éste detiene el script mientras que include sólo
>   emitirá una advertencia (`E_WARNING`) lo cual permite continuar el
>   script.

Conclusión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Todas importan código desde dicho archivo PHP, pero, ¿qué diferencia hay entre utilizar include() o require()? ¿Tengo que utilizar include() o include_once()?

```
require() vs include()
```

Ambas funciones importan o insertan el código contenido en el archivo.php dentro de otro. La diferencia puede deducirse de su nombre:

require() establece que el código del archivo invocado es requerido, es decir, obligatorio para el funcionamiento del programa. Por ello, si el archivo especificado en la función require() no se encuentra saltará un error “PHP Fatal error” y el programa PHP se detendrá.

include(), por el contrario, si no se encuentra dicho código, saltará un error tipo “Warning” y el programa seguirá ejecutándose (aunque como consecuencia de no incluirse el código puede que no funcione correctamente, o sí, depende de la situación).

Por tanto, es más común utilizar require(), pues lo más normal es que si llamamos al código de otro archivo es porque lo necesitamos. No obstante, se suele utilizar require para invocar código que, si no es incluido, el programa puede llegar a errores muy graves y por lo tanto, en dichas circunstancias, es mejor parar la ejecución del programa. Y utilizar include() para la llamada a archivos cuyo código no afecta a otras partes de la aplicación y que, por tanto, si no están, no afectará al resto del programa.

Por ejemplo, si tenemos un script PHP para mostrar artículos sería mejor utilizar require(), para cargar el código que realiza la consulta a la base de datos y recibe los datos del artículo a mostrar, mientras que podemos utilizar include() para invocar el archivo que contiene código html como puede ser el pie de la página web u otra parte de la plantilla.

```
require_once()/include_once() vs require()/include()
```

Las versiones require_once() e include_once() funcionan de la misma forma que sus respectivos, salvo que, al utilizar la versión _once, se impide la carga de un mismo archivo más de una vez.

Si incluimos el mismo código más de una vez corremos el riesgo de redeclaraciones de variables, funciones o clases. Es lógico pensar que por ello, es mejor siempre utilizar la versión _once. Si embargo, has de saber que estas versiones son más pesadas y consumen más recursos y por ello hay que utilizarlas sólo cuándo sea necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que confundes el tema, para incluir archivos
puedes hacer de varias maneras como lo son:

1. include 'archivo.php';   //Incluye de manera indefinida en tu archivo
2. include 'http:www.ruta.com/archivo.php';
3. include_once "archivo.php";//Incluye una vez en tu archivo

La idea de los includes es hacer algo generico.

Otra manera es hacer uso de Require que es similar a include cuya diferencias fue discutido en el siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633900/difference-between-include-and-require-in-php)

Si tu te refieres a Clases, como la siguiente:

```
<?php
class Cart {
var $items;

// Agregar $num artículos de $artnr al carrito

function add_item($artnr, $num) {
    $this->items[$artnr] += $num;
}

// Sacar $num artículos de $artnr fuera del carrito

function remove_item($artnr, $num) {
    if ($this->items[$artnr] > $num) {
        $this->items[$artnr] -= $num;
        return true;
    } elseif ($this->items[$artnr] == $num) {
        unset($this->items[$artnr]);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
}
?>
```

Puede ser incluida en un archivo externo gracias a include y retornar un valor

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que no existe una forma correcta o incorrecta, todas sirven, **pero si buenas o malas prácticas.**

Si pones el **require , estás obligando a la aplicación a que funcione con esa librería.**

> require es idéntico a include excepto que en caso de fallo producirá
>   un error fatal de nivel E_COMPILE_ERROR. En otras palabras, éste
>   detiene el script mientras que include sólo emitirá una advertencia
>   (E_WARNING) lo cual permite continuar el script.

[require](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require.php)

Include si no se puede pues emite un warning lo que no hace que se detenga la aplicación pero si que en el futuro pueda tener algun E_ERROR a causa de ello.

Todo depende.

Los casos con los once.

> La sentencia require_once es idéntica a r**equire excepto que PHP
>   verificará si el archivo ya ha sido incluido y si es así, no se
>   incluye** (require) de nuevo.

[require_once](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php)

Simplemente lo pone en php.net , que si está ya añadido no lo vuelve a añadir , es una manera de no llenar el código con otro ya repetido , por encima en ocasiones pueden dar un E_ERROR comentando que la clase en caso de que sean clases ya están repetidas.

Espero haberte explicado bien.